# Linear Search difference between O(1) and O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, linear-search

I am confused with the following two cases in linear search. Let me write the linear search algorithm here first.

Pseudo code for linear search

input: unsorted array A & key

output: index i such that A[i] = key

```
LinearSearch(A,low,high,key) 
if high < low    
   return NOT_Found
if A[low] = key
   return low
return LinearSearch(A,low+1,high,key)
```

The complexity is O(n) in most of the book. What is the difference between

1. Best-case runtime for linear search if key is present in the array [Ans: O(1)]
2. Best-case runtime for linear search if key isn't present in the array [Ans: O(n)]

What is the reason that when the key is present in the array, the complexity will reduce to O(1)? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is based on the best case. The best case would be that your key is on the first position (O(1)). More practical would be the average case which is in both cases O(n)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If key is not present in the array, is there any difference between best-case, average-case and worst-case?

Also, I have learned that the worst-case is theta(n) instead of O(n). How to explain the difference? Thanks.

Comment: If the key is not present, then the function will go through the whole array (O(n)) in every case (best, average and worst) if the key is present then the best case is O(1) because it could be on the first index (or first few). The average and worst case would still be O(n) because at the worst case the key is on the last index and the average would be approximately O(n/2) which is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason that when the key is present in the array, the
>   complexity will reduce to O(1)?

The presence of the key in the array makes a difference since consider the two cases:

- ***The key exists in the array***: then your running time **in best case** is **O(1)**, which means that you will have to move constant number of times in order to find it (e.g it will be the 2nd element, the 10th element, the 1st element generally sth constant). If the key exists then the worst case would be that it is in **O(n)** position in the array so you need at least **Ω(n)** steps and of course maximum steps is to search all n positions in array so **O(n)** which proves worst case **Θ(n)**.
- ***The key doesn't not exist***: In this case given an array and a key that does not exist in the array your linear search algorithm attempting to find it he **will have to check all elements** in order to find it because the algorithm has two termination conditions: the key is found or the array has ended. Of courses the key in this case will not be found and the algorithm will terminate after checking all elements. An observation here is that if the key does not exist the algorithm will do exactly **O(n)** steps both in best or worst case, if the key does not exist best and worst cases are the same since in both you search whole array!!

In both cases as explained the worst case is ***θ(n)***.